# Gradle - unable to track down transitive dependency

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have two modules: common and domain. Domain is a dependency of common. In domain, I'm trying to add the latest version of Spring Data Elasticsearch but it keeps reverting back to an old version. My domain's build.gradle file looks like this:

**domain build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
}
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis")
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:2.0.1.RELEASE")
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
}
```

The version for elasticsearch here is 2.0.1.RELASE However, if I run dependencyInsight in common, it is retrieving 1.3.4.RELEASE instead:

```
gradle dependencyInsight --dependency elasticsearch --configuration compile
:common:dependencyInsight

Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-elasticsearch/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-data-elasticsearch-1.3.4.RELEASE.pom

org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.5.2 (selected by rule) 
\--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:1.3.4.RELEASE
 \--- project :domain
      \--- compile

org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:1.3.4.RELEASE (selected by rule)

org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:2.0.1.RELEASE -> 1.3.4.RELEASE
\--- project :domain
 \--- compile
```

**common build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
}
}    

dependencies {
compile project(':domain')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'org.owasp.encoder:encoder:1.2'
compile 'com.ning:async-http-client:1.9.31'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:4.0.3.RELEASE'
compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.4'
compile 'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.4'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
}
```

Is there a reason why version 1.3.4.RELEASE is replacing 2.0.1.RELEASE?

Comment: How have you configured your common project? Can you post its `build.gradle` too?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I updated the post with common's build.gradle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're applying Spring Boot's Gradle plugin to your common project. That means that its dependency management will be controlling the versions of the project's dependencies. To get the version of Spring Data Elasticsearch that you want, you can override Boot's dependency management by adding the following:

```
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Another (hopefully) small question - is it possible to not apply the spring-boot plugin to common? Or do I need to apply it since one of its dependencies (domain) is using spring-boot?

Comment: I can't say for certain without seeing more of your code, but there's no need to apply it to your common project purely because the domain project has it applied.